# When importing modules from the pymks an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymks.fmks'

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed the pymks library but when I am trying to import modules from it to run examples provided in the github I get an error messsage.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-888235aa7043> in <module>
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 from toolz.curried import pipe, compose, map, curry
----> 4 from pymks.fmks.bases.primitive import discretize
      5 from pymks.fmks.localization import fit, predict, coeff_to_real
      6 from typing import Tuple

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymks.fmks'
```

Moreover, when I run:

```
python -c "import pymks; print(pymks.__version__)"
```

I get:

```
(tf2) C:\Users\Alienware\sfepy>python -c "import pymks; print(pymks.version)"
C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\numpy.libs\libopenblas.NOIJJG62EMASZI6NYURL6JBKM4EVBGM7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\numpy.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\numpy.libs\libopenblas.TXA6YQSD3GCQQC22GEQ54J2UDCXDXHWN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
stacklevel=1)
0.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `fmks` is merged into the `pymks`, see the references.

1. https://github.com/materialsinnovation/pymks/issues/353
2. https://github.com/materialsinnovation/pymks/issues/377
3. http://pymks.org/en/latest/bases.html